# why does FLASH_ErasePage reset my STM32F103C8?

Tags: stm32

Here is my program to write with EEPROM emulation in my stm32f103 flash memory.

```
void WriteEEPROM(char State){
uint32_t startAddress = 0x8019000;
FLASH_Unlock();
FLASH_ClearFlag(FLASH_FLAG_EOP|FLASH_FLAG_PGERR|FLASH_FLAG_WRPRTERR);
FLASH_ErasePage(startAddress);

    switch(State)
{
    case 1:FLASH_ProgramWord((startAddress+(0*32)+2),MainInfo.AZ);break;
    case 2:FLASH_ProgramWord((startAddress+(1*32)+2),MainInfo.EL);break;
}

FLASH_Lock();
```

}

but after calling this function it resets my MCU. I need to know why erasing the page 100 makes my MCU reset.

Comment: Have you enabled End-Of-Program interrupts, but failed to define a routine for the interrupt?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I don't get it what you said. could you clear your comment?  I have enabled some interrupts such as Timer,USART,DMA , ....

Comment: I only see the parts that you post here. You should know what your code does with the parts you are not posting, like you should know or look what other functions of the FLASH API you are using, and whether they enable EOP interrupts. Also, since erasing the flash makes it unavailable for a moment, do you have a watchdog enabled that might trigger during the time when the flash is erasing?

Comment: Have you enabled the watchdog timer and it's timing out and resetting the CPU during the long flash operation?

Comment: Thank you very much, Yes, it was the watchdog problem which needs more than 250mS.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Justme and jwh20 for your comments about memory access delay time. I just increase my watchdog timer.